# unable to add transitions to img using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhw2vhsq/2/), as header in this demo have transition effect I wanna to add image as header back ground I tried with this

css

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

html {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

caption, th, td {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

q, blockquote {
  quotes: none;
}
q:before, q:after, blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}

a img {
  border: none;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, menu, nav, section, summary {
  display: block;
}

* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-top: 330px;
  -moz-transition: padding-top 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: padding-top 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: padding-top 0.5s ease;
  transition: padding-top 0.5s ease;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #3498db;
  background: url("http://eridem.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/android-wallpaper.jpg") repeat-x width 100% height 300px position absolute; /**Here Im addig image/
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
header h1 {
  font-size: 42px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 230px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 100;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

img {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
 }

header nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
header nav a {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  line-height: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
header nav a:hover {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 34px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 2;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  line-height: 2;
  color: #7f8c8d;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

section {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/* Sticky Header Style */
/* ---------------------------------------- */
body.sticky-header {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
body.sticky-header header {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.9);
}
body.sticky-header header h1 {
  -moz-transform: scale(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0, 0);
  transform: scale(0, 0);
}
```

js

```
$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(winTop >= 30){
      $("body").addClass("sticky-header");
    }else{
      $("body").removeClass("sticky-header");
    }//if-else
  });//win func.
});//ready func.
```

and html is as

```
<body>

  <header>
    <h1>Header </h1>
    <nav>
      <a href="">Home</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <section>
      <h2> This is somestuff</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum enim sunt delectus, reiciendis omnis laudantium animi, et nulla quidem, aliquam aliquid. A consectetur deleniti voluptates eius neque, voluptate voluptatibus nostrum! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex libero cupiditate deserunt earum, fuga, ab labore esse animi, nihil est tenetur non delectus perferendis. Maxime accusamus ea rem sint at!</p>
    </section>
```

As you know I'm newbie in front-end web technologies and at SO as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Wrong to write Background attribute because you don't need to define which are width,height and position.

```
background: url("http://eridem.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/android-wallpaper.jpg");
background-size:cover;
```

i add background-size:cover for fit always image to background.

Comment: Great! that shows imgae in background, but what about adding trasitions to backgound image?

Comment: background-image don't support transition :( http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties

Comment: Sorry for taking your extra time & by the way thanks!

Comment: don't worry :) I'm happy to help